# Hide certain table columns from CSV with PHP

Tags: php, html, csv

I am generating an HTML table from a CSV file using the following code.

I'd like to only display columns with the following indexes:

`$idsColumnsWanted = array(0,1,19,16);`

How do I work this into my existing code?

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";

$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");

$first_line=false;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $row ="";

    if($first_line == false) {
         $row = "<thead><tr>";
         $col= "th";
    }
    else {
         $row = "<tr>";
         $col= "td";
    }


    $is_empty = false;

    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if ($cell !== '') {
            $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</".$col.">";
        } else {
            $is_empty = true;
        }
    }


    if($first_line == false) $row .= "</tr></thead>";
    else $row .= "</tr>";

    $first_line=true;

    if ($is_empty) {
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $row;
    }
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with in_array() function, and adding an index $i to your cycle:

```
$idsColumnsWanted = array(0,1,19,16);

echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>\n\n";

$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");

$first_line=false;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {

    // Restart column index
    $i = 0;

    $row ="";

    if($first_line == false) {
         $row = "<thead><tr>";
         $col= "th";
    }
    else {
         $row = "<tr>";
         $col= "td";
    }


    $is_empty = false;

    foreach ($line as $cell) {

        // Skips all columns not in your list
        if (! in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted) continue;

        if ($cell !== '') {
            $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "   </".$col.">";
        } else {
            $is_empty = true;
        }

        // Increase index
        $i++;

    }


    if($first_line == false) $row .= "</tr></thead>";
    else $row .= "</tr>";

    $first_line=true;

    if ($is_empty) {
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $row;
    }

}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to change your code to:

```
$idsColumnsWanted = array(0,1,19,16);
for($i=0;$i<count($line);$i++) {
    if (in_array($i, $idsColumnsWanted)) {
        if ($cell !== '') {
            $row .= "<".$col.">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</".$col.">";
        } else {
            $is_empty = true;
        }
    }
}
```